# dotnet publish and web.config?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How I understand it is that `web.config` is required when running an ASP.NET Core web application on Azure App Service:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyProgram.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

`dotnet publish -c Release` doesn't create this `web.config`, so I created itself and put it in the solution (odd, because I've never had to do this before).

But the issue I am experiencing is that it does not publish the `web.config` file? It seems to ignores it.

The only way I can get my application working in the Web App is to manually copy the `web.config` file into the wwwroot folder using Kudu.

Note: This is a framework-dependent deployment (FDD), not self-contained, and using .NET Core 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We finally figured it out. The project type was incorrect. It needs to be:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

And not

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```